# REST API user and client authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt

I am building a REST API as the backend for a mobile app. I would like to check if the requests made to the API are coming from our mobile app. However, the API will require end users to login in order to access certain endpoints.

My questions is, how could I authenticate all incoming requests to make sure they are coming from our own app, while also authenticating the end users for some requests?

I was thinking of sending an API key with all requests in the Authentication HTTP Header to authenticate the mobile app, and (separated by a comma) also send along a JWT for authenticating the end-user. While this could work, it seems a bit "hacky".

> What is the standard way of authenticating both the mobile app and the
>   end-user of the mobile app at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Using an application token and a user-specific session token is one method of separating authentication of the two. The application token would be unique for your application, and should be obfuscated so that inspection of the client's binary would not lead to easy detection of the token. The user-specific session token should be generated when the user is logged in. The client adds this user session key to future API calls, the server will check if the session key is valid, and can use it to look up any session state stored for the client.

However, optimally, you would implement the full oauth2 spec. as outlined in this [ultimate guide to mobile API security](https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security):

> Here’s how OAuth2 token authentication works from a user perspective
> (OAuth2 calls this the password grant flow):
>
> 1. A user opens up your mobile app and is prompted for their username or email and password.
> 2. You send a POST request from your mobile app to your API service with the user’s username or email and password data included (OVER SSL!).
> 3. You validate the user credentials, and create an access token for the user that expires after a certain amount of time.
> 4. You store this access token on the mobile device, treating it like an API key which lets you access your API service.
> 5. Once the access token expires and no longer works, you re-prompt the user for their username or email and password.
>
> What makes OAuth2 great for securing APIs is that it doesn’t require you to store API keys in an unsafe environment. Instead, it will generate access tokens that can be stored in an untrusted environment temporarily.
>
> This is great because even if an attacker somehow manages to get a hold of your temporary access token, it will expire! This reduces damage potential (we’ll cover this in more depth in our next article).

Comment: Thanks for the great info. OAuth2 sounds like a promising option but it uses a username and password combo. My API does not require the user of the mobile app to be logged in, only for some endpoints. How would I use OAuth2 in this case?

Comment: I will direct you to this useful explanation of oauth2 which should hopefully answer all your questions: https://gist.github.com/seanpianka/8a4d2fd23c6b947f3d58c1e378e17d7a